adding security headers in wso2am-4.0.0 (sts & csp & referer headers)
I'm trying to add those two headers in all portals as guided by my companies security team. So far I've tried adding somem configurations in the deployment.toml. This only brings the sts header in the devportal but not in other portals.
[[tomcat.carbon.filter]]
name = "HttpHeaderSecurityFilter"
class = "org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter"
init_param_name = "hstsMaxAgeSeconds"
init_param_value = "15768000"

[[tomcat.carbon.filter_mapping]]
name = "HttpHeaderSecurityFilter"
url_pattern = ["*"]


I've also tried adding the filters in the web.xml file that is available here: wso2am-4.0.0/repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF but this configurations seem to be rewritten on startup.
[2024-04-29 16:13:46,247]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository/resources/security/sslprofiles.xml
[2024-04-29 16:13:46,249]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository/resources/security/listenerprofiles.xml
[2024-04-29 16:13:46,249]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository/conf/deployment.toml
[2024-04-29 16:13:46,250]  INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml


Anyone know how I could solve this?

Try adding these
[[tomcat.filter]]
name = "httpHeaderSecurity"
class = "org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter"
async_supported = true

[tomcat.filter.init_params]
hstsEnabled = true
hstsMaxAgeSeconds = 31536000
hstsIncludeSubDomains = true

[[tomcat.filter_mapping]]
name = "httpHeaderSecurity"
url_pattern = "/*"
dispatchers = "REQUEST"




Thanks I've checked that it works. My final question is, is there a similar solution for csp headers or does wso2 not support that?

I added the above toml configuration to one of my gateway profile nodes hoping they will be applied to my REST API response headers, but its not working. Can you please let me know if there is a way to apply the security header config globally to all APIs in the gateway ?
